# Adding elements dynamically to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have below scenario:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("John");
list.add("is");
list.add("good");
list.add("boy");
int count = 2;
if (list.get(count-1)!= null)
{
    list.set(count+1, "mike");
    list.set(count+1,"Tysosn");
}
```

expected output: `("john","is","good","mike","Tyson","boy")`

But i am getting array out of bond exception.

Can some one please suggest.

Comment: Got it :)
Thanks Guglielmo Moretti

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? At which line does the exception occur? I also think that you're using "set" wrong. "Set" will replace an item, not add it somewhere in between.

Comment: I did not get any exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [java.util.List#set(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) to replace the element at any position

Use [java.util.List#add(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) to add the element to any position.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ArrayList.add(int index, E element) method to achieve desired result like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListInsertTest {
    @Test
    public void testWithArrayList() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("John");
        list.add("is");
        list.add("good");
        list.add("boy");

        list.add(3, "mike");
        list.add(4, "Tyson");
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Note from documentation of ArrayList:

```
/**
     * Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this
     * list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and
     * any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
     *
     * @param index index at which the specified element is to be inserted
     * @param element element to be inserted
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void add(int index, E element) {
```